# Serializing ReferenceProperty in Appengine Datastore to JSON

Tags: python, json, serialization, google-cloud-datastore

I am using the following code to serialize my appengine datastore to JSON

```
class DictModel(db.Model):
    def to_dict(self):
        return dict([(p, unicode(getattr(self, p))) for p in self.properties()])


 class commonWordTweets(DictModel):
    commonWords = db.StringListProperty(required=True)
    venue = db.ReferenceProperty(Venue, required=True, collection_name='commonWords')
```

class Venue(db.Model):
    id = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    fourSqid = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    twitter_ID = db.StringProperty(required=True)

This returns the following JSON response

```
 [
  {
    "commonWords": "[u'storehouse', u'guinness', u'badge', u'2011"', u'"new', u'mayor', u'dublin)']",
    "venue": "<__main__.Venue object at 0x1028ad190>"
  }
]
```

How can I return the actual venue name to appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, although it's not exactly your question, it's strongly recommended to use [simplejson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson) to produce json, rather than trying to turn structures into json strings yourself.

To answer your question, the ReferenceProperty just acts as a reference to your Venue object. So you just use its attributes as per normal.

Try something like:

```
cwt = commonWordTweets()   # Replace with code to get the item from your datastore
d = {"commonWords":cwt.commonWords, "venue": cwt.venue.name}
jsonout = simplejson.dumps(d)
```